# Setting a file path as text to clipboard in LUA

Tags: lua

I am a total noob to LUA.

I need a script that will just copy a file path as text to the clipboard. That's it. I absolutely cannot figure it out. I keep getting the error:

attempt to call a nil value (global 'set_clipboard')

Here is the file path I am trying to copy to the clipboard:

D:_Google Drive_Acting\VO\Room Tone\roomtone.wav

This must be a simple script, right?

Comment: "*This must be a simple script, right?*" Why "must" there be? Lua is not Python; it is not a "do everything" scripting environment. Its primary designed purpose is to be tiny and efficient for use in embedded environments. That's not to say that Lua is not functional as a command scripting language, but it is a no-frills system that doesn't offer much out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows you can do this:

```
filename = 'my_filename.txt'
io.popen('clip','w'):write(filename):close()
```

Comment: Add `:close()` at the end to update the clipboard after the command is executed.

Comment: Edited, thanks!  I tested stand-alone and it worked so I didn't notice this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in function for that.

In Mac OS, you can do this

```
function set_clipboard(text)
    io.popen('pbcopy','w'):write(text):close()
end
```

Apparently, in Windows you can use `clip` instead of `pbcopy`. I don't know about Linux.